# Remove minimum text length limit

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, character-limit

Please remove the minimum text length limit. It is very annoying! Not once I just hadn't what to say more but I was forced to.

At least to higher reputations.

Comment: Explain, please. I added some counter-example in the comments below.

Comment: Care to share some examples of posts that would have been better had they been below the limit?

Comment: @Bathsheba voting on feature request  just because "this takes courage" is wrong, and hurting Meta as whole. The downvotes exist exactly for that purpose: let the community know how many people are against the requested feature. If one choose not to understand that and be offended/insulted by downvotes, that's their problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thank you for your helpful comment. I stand corrected. I'll withdraw my comment, and the upvote.

Comment: @Cai, Can't find them ATM.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Wow, you could have also said that they are for letting the community know how many people are for the requested feature too. That shows the bias in this community.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it goes both ways, of course.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, In theory, in practice, not.

Comment: umm... how not? There are great many feature requests with high score.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, So, I have two arguments on the single two answers, with no reply, yet this was marked as declined, instead of waiting for the discussions to end. This feels like communism.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei no, it feels like the team is doing what's best for the site. Sometimes even popular requests with lots of upvotes are declined, [this is the most famous example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I'm not saying that this shouldn't be declined, but that my questions should be answered. The problem is that it was declined too soon, without the right of reply.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei there's nothing else to say, the existing answers are more than enough, with valid reasons why to decline. No point in having more answers saying "yes, the other answers are correct".

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Answers to [my](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297740/remove-minimum-text-length-limit?noredirect=1#comment966379_297742) [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297740/remove-minimum-text-length-limit?noredirect=1#comment966350_297741).

Comment: I guess they have nothing constructive to say. At some point discussion degrades and one side simply does not have anything to add/say without provoking negative response. At this point, it's usually better to simply back off. I assume that's the case here, without getting too deep into this, as both answerers are long time members of meta.

Comment: If you really want to get response, the last thing you still can do is to create a new chat room and invite both. They will be notified, and might join.

Answer (score 10):

No.

Every time I wanted to post "No" as an answer, I realised there was more to say. Even here, where no would be a short, succinct answer - I'm sure you want to know why I said no.

There's always more to say. Add examples to posts. Post meaningful comments that's more than +1.

The limits are there to keep out trivial posts, and work well for keeping the worst of it out. .

Comment: Every time I wanted to post "Yes" as an answer, I realized there was nothing more to say. I'm not saying I always post 3 letters replies, but when it happens, I get annoyed at the fact that I have to put dots just to get past the checker (which also doesn't work, knowing I can get past it like this). As I said I can swear in replies and they are worse than a "Yes", do you agree?

Comment: I've also said yes. Then went on to explain why I was right. It is fun. You should try it

Comment: Nice irony. Original example comment (at an answer that was later removed): "Are you sure the label is not nil?". My answer: "Yes".

Comment: Yes, why? How are you sure?

Comment: I didn't have to ask "why" because if the label was nil, the original question wouldn't make sense. And, why would I ask him "How are you sure?" if he asked me "Are you sure ... ?"?

Answer (score 1):

The comment to which you allude (prior to your question edit) *could* have been more helpful if you had written "yes, because " and so on.

So, for me at least, you have not found a counter-example to the idea that a minimum level of verbosity is a good way of maintaining the quality of questions, answers, and comments.

It also helps protect against "thank you", "plus one", "yes", "no" type responses which do little more than add clutter.

Let's keep it as it is.

Comment: Because what? The label was not `nil` period.

Comment: But it doesn't protect against "f**k you very much" or even "plus one (.........)", so it's almost useless. Also, that's what flags are for.

Comment: Responding to flags is a manual effort. The poor mods are busy enough.

Comment: Better yet, it should check for a couple of common cluttering answers and block those, not "yes" which is one of the most common answers.

Comment: Or at least show a "Let's start a chat" button everytime, where you can type what you want.

Comment: So? (..........)

Comment: Pun intended ...